# IIS 7.5 / windows 7 64bit / Nwsgi 2.1 - web.config configuration error

Tags: web-config, ironpython, iis-7.5

I'm getting "Configuration Error" from IIS 7.5 Widows 7 64bit with NWSGI 2.1 - using defalt web.config for NWSGI

I think that NWSGI need to be recompiled for 64 bit, any suggestions on what the cause is!?!?

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

`Source Error:`

```
Line 5:      </configSections>
Line 6:      <system.web>
Line 7:          <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
Line 8:          <httpHandlers>
Line 9:              <add verb="*" path="*.wsgi" type="NWSGI.WsgiHandler, NWSGI, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=41e64ddc1bf1fc86"/>
```

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HelloWorld\web.config    Line: 7

Answer (score 1):

Check the Framework version of the Application pool inside which your application is running

Comment: I set DefaultAppPool to use .Net Framework v4.0 - works fine thx

Comment: You might try changing application pool's “Enable 32.Bit Applications” property to true in IIS Manager.